# Codeigniter insert_batch issue

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, foreach

Im trying to insert multiple value to database using insert_batch. But its showing me error.

**Controller:**

```
    public function add()
    {
        $data['title'] = $this->input->post('title');
        $data['file'] = $this->input->post('file');
        $this->user->in();
    }
```

**Model:**

```
 public function in()
 {
        $data['title'] = $this->input->post('title');
        $data['file'] = $this->input->post('file');

        foreach ($title as $key => $n) {

                        $insert = array(
                                'title' => $n,
                                'file' => $file[$key]
                                );
                        // echo $n."->".$file[$key].'<br>' ;
            }
            $this->db->insert_batch('title',$insert);  //line 42 in user.php (error)
            // return $query;
 }
```

**view:**

```
<?php echo form_open('location/add'); ?>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="title[]"><br>
  <input type="text" name="file[]">
</div>
<br><br>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="title[]"><br>
  <input type="text" name="file[]">
</div>   <br><br>   
<div>
  <input type="text" name="title[]"><br>
  <input type="text" name="file[]">
</div>
<input type="submit" name="" value="enter">
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

But when I run this it's showing me error like this:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> You must use the "set" method to update an entry.
>
> Filename: models/User.php
>
> Line Number: 47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

```
$insert = array(
   'title' => $n,
   'file' => $file[$key]
);
```

It should be like following

```
 $insert[] = array(
     'title' => $n,
     'file' => $data['file'][$key]
 );
```

and instead of this

```
 foreach ($title as $key => $n) {...
```

Use

```
 foreach ($data['title'] as $key => $n) {....
```

Comment: What if I want to upload a file like this? `<input type="file" name="file[]">`

Comment: Thanks bro.. its working for me. But I can't insert the file names to my DB. Can you please help me. This is my complete code [Code](http://pastebin.com/iEeAjkFH)

Comment: can you help me to do this?

Comment: please check my link given already, I think this is the solution you are looking for

Comment: I check that link but I couldn't find solution for this issue. The only problem is I'm not getting the file name

Comment: you may create a new question with issues & code details you tried.. I'll check

Comment: [Please check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894358/get-filename-as-array-after-upload-in-codeigniter)